# Extending Spring Cache Interceptor for collecting custom metrics

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cache

I'm trying to collect the cache metrics in detail, capture them as events, for instance; object is hit from cache, or it was a miss, it took X milliseconds, not just aggregated metrics. Since Spring Cache abstraction is already good enough, I thought I would find something like interceptors or filters but there does not seem one. How would one go with it, implementing a CacheManager without themselves? By reference, I'm using Redis cache with Lettuce Client, but would prefer the Cache abstraction to stay and capture cache events in a central place.

- Being relatively new to Spring, I'm not even sure what's the best way to do these. I tried creating my CacheManager wrapping redis one, but not sure how it plays with auto-configuration.
- My own cache manager just proxies all the calls to the wrapped one, but it does not know if it's whether a cache hit or miss, they are called even if the cache is empty with the actual method call.

Comment: If that is your full function it actually breaks proper execution. What metrics do you need that aren't provided out-of-the-box?

Comment: It's not full function, it's just the signature I'm trying to match but to no avail. I want to capture how long does it take to get the cache, and log them somewhere else, but I need it per-request, hence I'm not interested in aggregated metrics.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for `RedisCache.getStatistics`?

It returns `CacheStatistics`.

```java
public interface CacheStatistics {

    /**
     * @return the name of the {@link RedisCache}.
     */
    String getCacheName();

    /**
     * @return number of put operations on the cache.
     */
    long getPuts();

    /**
     * @return the total number of get operations including both {@link #getHits() hits} and {@link #getMisses() misses}.
     */
    long getGets();

    /**
     * @return the number of cache get hits.
     */
    long getHits();

    /**
     * @return number of cache get misses.
     */
    long getMisses();

    /**
     * @return the number of {@link #getGets() gets} that have not yet been answered (neither {@link #getHits() hit} nor
     *         {@link #getMisses() miss}).
     */
    default long getPending() {
        return getGets() - (getHits() + getMisses());
    }

    /**
     * @return number of cache removals.
     */
    long getDeletes();

    /**
     * @param unit the time unit to report the lock wait duration.
     * @return lock duration using the given {@link TimeUnit} if the cache is configured to use locking.
     */
    long getLockWaitDuration(TimeUnit unit);

    /**
     * @return initial point in time when started statistics capturing.
     */
    Instant getSince();

    /**
     * @return instantaneous point in time of last statistics counter reset. Equals {@link #getSince()} if never reset.
     */
    Instant getLastReset();

    /**
     * @return the statistics time.
     */
    default Instant getTime() {
        return Instant.now();
    }
}
```

Comment: I've combined this with using my own StatisticsCollector, with default threading model, I could use ThreadLocals to collect metrics per request. However I still lack the ability to measure the duration, but this can be achieved by copying (it's protected class) `DefaultRedisCacheWriter` 's `execute` method.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seems, that `Lettuce` offers the availability to measure the hit/miss of a cache.
`Lettuce` has some built-in metrics like a histrogram or latency. [A link to the wiki](https://github.com/lettuce-io/lettuce-core/wiki/Command-Latency-Metrics).

You can try to grab some metrics from redis itself. Have a look to the [redis-docs](https://docs.redislabs.com/latest/rs/administering/monitoring-metrics/prometheus-metrics-definitions/).
There you can get some more data like `read/write hit/miss`  or `evicted_objects`.

All in all: I don't think that a object-level metric (= a per-key metric?) isn't really helpful. Did you want to know, how fast is `object-id-abc` vs `object-id-def`?

But if you really need that: You can define the `RedisClient` as bean by yourself with a custom implementation (`proxy-pattern` or override some of the methods). Then you can measure the time.
I see no way, to get the cache hit/miss from redis. Maybe you will find something in the [lettuce-github-repo](https://github.com/lettuce-io/lettuce-core) and/or the [redis-api](https://redis.io/).
You can try to archive that with the execution-time (when it takes long to get a value, it was maybe not in cache), but this is very unstable and you will get a lot of false positives.

---

### Edit

As a other idea: In your proxy you can store the metric how often a key was requested (it should be measure as timeunit like `requests/hour`). Combined  with the execution-time you are near to the `cache hit/miss`-metric.